# Power associative basis implies not nilpotent?

Tags: nilpotence, nonassociative-algebras, jordan-algebras

Consider a non-associative commutative unital algebra of finite dimension where the product is defined by a cayley table such that elements are generated with real number coefficients
$(a_0, \dots, a_n) $
for a basis
$\{1, i_1, \dots, i_n \}$
and we have a basis so that
$ i_k^2 \in \{ -1, +1 \}$.

This implies the answer can be given in the form of a cayley table for multiplying the finite dimensional basis $\{1, i_1, \dots, i_n \}$.

So our algebra is of the form $ a_0 + a_1 i_1 + a_2 i_2 + ...$, addition is as usual and products are defined by a cayley table relating the basis elements $\{1, i_1, \dots, i_n \}$
and we have a basis so that
$ i_k^2 \in \{ -1, +1 \}$.

Assume the basis elements are also power-associative.

Does this imply the whole algebra is power-associative and nilpotent elements do not exist ??

Comment: I believe it does not, let's see what I can do. Consider the algebra generated by {1,a,b} with $a^2=b^2=-1$ and $ab=ba=1$. Every power of $a,b,1$ is well-defined and $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2=0$.

Comment: @2ndYearFreshman but $a = - b$ ? Giving $a+b = 0$ and $(a+b)^2 = 0^2 $.
I do not believe $a$ and $b$ are linearly independant hence not a basis.
Right ?

Comment: Could you explain to me how did you conclude that $a+b=0$ from the definition that I gave? Just as a remark, this is not a division algebra so $ab=0$ does not imply $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are just i and -i from the complex numbers.
$1/a = - a $ implies that $ a^2 = -1 $ and thus $ -  a = b$ because $ab = 1$
Assuming unique inverses ofcourse.

Comment: Because $ax=1$ has infinitely many solutions (e.g $r(a+b), r\in\mathbb{R}$) your very last argument won't work. To conclude $-a=b$ from $(-a)a=1=ab$ you need some sort of cancellation law or associativy, that is, $a^{-1}(ab)=a$ or uniqueness of solution for equations of the form $xy=z$ with $x,z$ fixed.

Comment: I Thought every commutative algebra required uniqueness of equations of the form $xy = z $ with $x,z$ fixed !?
If not what are the names to distinguish those that do and those that don't ?

Comment: I know the ones that you want by "division algebras". Consider for example a zero-algebra (one in such the product of any two element is always 0), it is naturally comutative but $ay=0$ has an infinite number of solutions (sure I am assuming the algebra has a infinite number of elements).

Comment: If inverses are not unique ; is $x 1/x $ always equal to $1$ ?? because the inverse of x is not unique. And since x^0 = x/x does that not imply it is not power-associative ? Or even that powers are not uniquely defined !!??

Comment: OK consider this if (a+b)^2 = 0 and a(a+b) = -1 + ab = -1 + 1 then a(a+b) = 0.
Since a(a+b) = (a+b)(a+b) we get that b(a+b) = 0.
Is that not a problem ??

Comment: Powers may not behave well, for instance, it may happen that $x²x²\neq x²(xx²)$.

Comment: I don't see why it would be a problem, if you could enlighten me. If the dimension is finite then being free of zero divisors is the same as being a division algebra. The algebra that I gave to you can not be a division algebra so one would expect that $xy=0$ for many non zero pairs of $x,y$.

Comment: 1) It feels like a bicomplex number with a missing unit.
2) It probably has no matrix representation , does it ??
3) It probably has elements without square roots
4) seems to miss so many desirable properties ...

I would love to see a matrix representation !

Comment: WAIT I think I understand something :

1/(a + b) = c = 1/a if bc = 0 
So zero divisors imply imply nonunique multiplicative inverses ??

Or am I incorrect here ??

Comment: Another further example, the Sedenions (are not commutative, unfortunatelly) have many non zero elements satisfying $xy=0$ and has a Cayley table. I don't work with matrix representation so I can't even say if there is one. It is just a strange algebra so don't expect it to behave any good.

Comment: But the sedenions have no element $z$ such that $z^2 = 0$ right ?

Comment: 1/(a + b) = c = 1/a if bc = 0 so that only works for zero-divisors.
It should not be true otherwise ?? hmm confused ...

Comment: Yes, no nilpotent elements on Sedenenions (except 0). Yes, in a commutative algebra, if $bc=0$ and $ba=1$ for some $a$, then $c+a$ also satisfies $b(a+c)=1$.

Comment: wait I see the problem.
Since $a$ is a zero divisor ( a (a+b) = 0 ) ; a should not have a multiplicative inverse ... but it has multiplicative inverse b and - a !!

Comment: For non associative algebras, an element may be a zero divisor and also have multiplicative inverse, that happens in the sedenions case.

Comment: Also $(a+b)/a = 1 + b*-b = 2$. But this means $a + b = 2 a$ ( so not linear independant !? also $(a+b)/a$ is real but ( $(a+b)/a )^{-1}$ is not even defined and not $1/2$ ???

Comment: That symbol $"1/a"$ seems to be confusing you. It is only meaningful when there is "only and one" element satisfying $ab=1$ and we call this "the inverse of $a$". This algebra has many of what you are calling "1/a" so it is not meaningful at all and even more, not well-defined.

Comment: An algebra such that division is bad defined hmm sounds barely like an algebra to me. But that is subjective I guess.
For associative algebra's having a matrix representation a zero divisor has no inverse i think ( since determinant of zero divisor is 0. ) 
Could you give me an example from the sedenions where a zero divisor has a multiplicative inverse ?? thank you !

Comment: As a bonus for you last comment. In any associative algebra, zero divisors have no inverse since if $ab=1$ and $bc=0$ for some non-zero $c$, then $c=(ab)c=a(bc)=a.0=0$, a contradiction (see that being associative is crucial here).

Comment: $(e_3+e_{10})(e_6-e_{15})=0$, where $e_i$ are the base elements. It depends a little on notation, so I will give you a wikipedia article that lists some zero divisors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedenion